# Conflict Protobuf version when using Opencv and Tensorflow c++

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am currently trying to use Tensorflow's shared library in a non-bazel project, so I creat a .so file from tensorflow using bazel.

but when I launch a c++ program that uses both Opencv and Tensorflow, it makes me the following error :

> [libprotobuf FATAL external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:78] This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.1.0).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "/build/mir-pkdHET/mir-0.21.0+16.04.20160330/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
>
> what():  This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.1.0).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "/build/mir-pkdHET/mir-0.21.0+16.04.20160330/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
>   Abandon (core dumped)

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: What's actually unclear about that message?

Comment: the problem is even if I try to install the 3.1.0 version I still get the same error

Comment: ***This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.1.0). Contact the program author for an update.*** Did you recompile the library using protobuf 3.1.0??

Comment: yes I did it, but i still get the same error

Comment: Did you recompile all the `.proto` files also?

Comment: which .proto files should I recompile ?

Comment: when I write 'protoc --version' I find 'libprotoc 3.1.0'

Comment: I had a similar problem. I had to statically link protobuf into one of my shared libraries. If you `nm -D` either shared library, you will see conflicting symbols for Protobuf. Good Luck! It was super painful for me

Comment: @H.Abdessamad I found a solution to this that I posted as an answer, in case you're still having trouble with this.

Comment: I had this same problem. Uninstalled the protobuf libraries from system using `sudo apt-get remove --purge libprotobuf10 libprotobuf-dev` and then (after recompiling) it worked. 
However, that uninstalled other libraries I needed in the process. So when it compiles, it find and links to the wrong runtime library, somehow, even though it's a sub-dependency (a dependency of another lib file). I think this is a great example of just how *broke* the whole C++ compilation/linking library environment set up is.

Comment: Just a warning, DON'T do `sudo apt-get remove --purge libprotobuf10 libprotobuf-dev`, it's gonna uninstall your desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that the program was complied using headers (`.h` files) from protobuf 2.6.1. These headers are typically found in `/usr/include/google/protobuf` or `/usr/local/include/google/protobuf`, though they could be in other places depending on your OS and how the program is being built. You need to update these headers to version 3.1.0 and recompile the program.

Comment: I have the right header in `/usr/local/include/google/protobuf`..... I found that some of the .so opencv files depend on a `libprotobuf-lite.so.9` (which is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`).

Comment: Well, the message says that the program was compiled with old protobuf headers. I am the one who wrote that error message and I can assure you that it is not wrong. You'll have to figure out how the program ended up with old headers. Another possibility is that the program's build system downloads its own copy of the headers (with the wrong version) into the local build, rather than use the system-installed copy. But I don't know. There are infinite possibilities here.

Comment: you are right, there are infinite possibilities here.
when I installed Opencv, I do it with GTK3 ( but the problem is gtk3 depend on the protobuf 2.6.1 ) thats why I see this error when I use Opencv and tensorflow in the same cpp file.

to solve my problem, I installed opencv with GTK2 which doesn't depand on protobuf 2.6.1. I thank you for your help @Kenton Varda.

Comment: Ah hah, so it was actually that a library that you depend on -- which you hadn't recompiled -- was built using old headers. Makes sense.

Comment: I feel that having to recompile an entire library (opencv) just because the used libraries have the same library sub-dependency but with different versions (protobuf versions 2.6 and 3.1 in the case) isn't the best approach.

Comment: @Bersan To be clear, this isn't a problem specific to protobuf. The nature of dynamic linking on Linux makes it unsafe to link multiple versions of the same library into the same process, and the nature of C++ makes it mostly infeasible for new versions of a C++ library to provide backwards-compatible ABIs. That said, future protobuf versions should perhaps consider using C++11 inline namespaces to solve this problem; that feature wasn't available when protobuf was first released.

Answer (score 7):

You should rebuild TensorFlow with a linker script to avoid making third party symbols global in the shared library that Bazel creates. This is how the Android Java/JNI library for TensorFlow is able to coexist with the pre-installed protobuf library on the device (look at the build rules in [tensorflow/contrib/android](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/android) for a working example)

Here's a BUILD file that I adapted from the Android library to do this:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

licenses(["notice"])  # Apache 2.0

exports_files(["LICENSE"])

load(
    "//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl",
    "tf_copts",
    "if_android",
)

exports_files([
    "version_script.lds",
])

# Build the native .so.
# bazel build //tensorflow/contrib/android_ndk:libtensorflow_cc_inference.so \
#   --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool \
#   --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
#   --cpu=armeabi-v7a
LINKER_SCRIPT = "//tensorflow/contrib/android:version_script.lds"

cc_binary(
    name = "libtensorflow_cc_inference.so",
    srcs = [],
    copts = tf_copts() + [
        "-ffunction-sections",
        "-fdata-sections",
    ],
    linkopts = if_android([
        "-landroid",
        "-latomic",
        "-ldl",
        "-llog",
        "-lm",
        "-z defs",
        "-s",
        "-Wl,--gc-sections",
        "-Wl,--version-script",  # This line must be directly followed by LINKER_SCRIPT.
        LINKER_SCRIPT,
    ]),
    linkshared = 1,
    linkstatic = 1,
    tags = [
        "manual",
        "notap",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib",
        LINKER_SCRIPT,
    ],
)
```

And the contents of `version_script.lds`:

```
{
  global:
    extern "C++" {
        tensorflow::*;
    };
  local:
    *;
};
```

This will make everything in the `tensorflow` namespace global and available through the library, while hiding the reset and preventing it from conflicting with protobuf.

(wasted a ton of time on this so I hope it helps!)

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a pretty serious problem! I get the below error similar to you:

```
$./ceres_single_test 
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:78] This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.1.0).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "/build/mir-pkdHET/mir-0.21.0+16.04.20160330/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
Aborted
```

My workaround:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo mkdir BACKUP
sudo mv libmirprotobuf.so* ./BACKUP/
```

Now, the executable under test works, cool. What is not cool, however, is that things like gedit no longer work without running from a shell that has the BACKUP path added to LD_LIBRARY_PATH :-(
  Hopefully there's a better fix out there?

Comment: I have found a solution to this that I posted as an answer, if you're still having trouble.

Comment: I'm confused, why would this work? You moved the protobuf library, and now it is no longer found? Therefore, it must be using the library installed on another path, right? If that's the case, you could try [invoking the executable while specifying the path of the correct protobuf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24814/333961)

Answer (score 0):

The error complains about the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version. This error is coming from the GTK3 library. GTK3 use Protocol Buffer 2.6.1.  If you use GTK3 to support Opencv, you get this error. The easiest way to fix this, you can use QT instead of GTK3.

If you use Cmake GUI to install Opencv, just select QT support instead of using GTK3. You can install QT using the following command.

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

rebuild libprotobuf with `-Dprotobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`

then `make install` to cover the older version