# Error when importing cv2 in python

Tags: python, opencv

when I run `import cv2` in python3, I get the following error:

```
This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer 
 runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version 
(3.1.0).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled 
the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same 
version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version 
verification failed in "/build/mir-ui6vjS/mir-
0.26.3+16.04.20170605/obj-x86_64-linux-
gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 
'google::protobuf::FatalException'
 what():  This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the 
Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the 
installed version (3.1.0).  Contact the program author for an update.  
If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are 
from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  
(Version verification failed in "/build/mir-ui6vjS/mir-
0.26.3+16.04.20170605/obj-x86_64-linux-
gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964212/conflict-protobuf-version-when-using-opencv-and-tensorflow-c), it says I need to update my header files. How do I actually do that?

What is the command to do so?